# entity framework, oracle, guid endianness

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, guid, endianness

I use EF 4 with oracle. I have a table with a RAW column containing guids. 
These guids are imported from a sql server db by some process I cannot control.

My issue is that if I simply use EF to create a guid property in my entity, the first 3 parts of the guid come out with the endianess reversed to what .net interfacing with SQL server expects. Therefore the guids do not match up anymore.

To illustrate, this is what the Guids look like:

```
Oracle:                 B0EFF3431D460639E04010AC1D044ED2
Sql Server:             B0EFF343-1D46-0639-E040-10AC1D044ED2
Entity Guid property:  {43f3efb0-461d-3906-e040-10ac1d044ed2}
```

I understand why this could happen and as a workaround, I added a new property to the entity that converts between the endianness like this:

```
byte[] bigEndianGuidArray = EfGeneratedGuidProperty.ToByteArray();
string guidString = BitConverter.ToString(bigEndianGuidArray, 0).Replace("-", string.Empty);
return new Guid(guidString);
```

This works, but it does not seem very reasonable to me to do this raw -> guid via EF -> byte array -> string -> string replace -> guid conversion.

Is there a better way? Ideally simply telling EF somehow to do the conversion correcly for me.

Comment: It's sad that this issue still exists in EF6